# How to get the grandparent data in resolver graphql?

Tags: rest, api, graphql, wrapper

I'm new to GraphQL. I am wrapping a REST API wiht GraphQL, my problem is that I don't get the 
ingredients of restaurant dishes (grandparents), just get the ingredients of a dish (parents) .This is my schema

```
type Restaurant{
  id_restaurant: String
  name: String
  dishes:[Dish]
}

type Dish{
  id_dish: String
  name: String
  ingredients:[Ingredient]
}

type Ingredient{
  id_ingredient: String
  name: String
}

type Query{
  restaurants: [Restaurant]
  dishes: [Dish]
  ingredients: [Ingredient] 
}
```

These are my resolvers

```
const mainURL = `https://my_apy_example`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    restaurants: () => { return fetch(`${mainURL}/restaurants`).then(res => res.json()) },
    dishes: () => { return fetch(`${mainURL}/dishes`).then(res => res.json()) },
    ingredients: () => { return fetch(`${mainURL}/ingredients`).then(res => res.json()) },  
  },
  Restaurant: {
    dishes: parent => {
      const { id_restaurant } = parent
      return fetch(`${mainURL}/dishes?id_restaurant=${id_restaurant}`).then(res => res.json())
    },
  },
  Dish: {
    ingredients: parent => {
      const { id_dish } = parent
      return fetch(`${mainURL}/ingredients?id_dish=${id_dish}`).then(res => res.json())
    },
  },
}
```

I assumed that the Dish resolver also resolved the dishes of Restaurant but I think I need other resolver for this, I was wrong.

This query doesn't show the ingredients

```
query{
  restaurants{
    name
    dishes{
      name
      ingredients{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query shows the ingredients

```
query{
  dishes{
    name
    ingredients{
      name
    }
  }
}
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: The resolver for the `ingredients` field will be called anytime a Recipe object is returned -- whether your root query is `restaurants` or `dishes`. Thanks for including all the relevant code, but I'm not quite sure if I'm following what problem you're trying to resolve. Can you provide additional details as to what exactly is not working with the code that you posted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When the restaurants is the root query, the ingredients field shows empty, like this []. I think the resolution function for dishes of a restaurant does not necessarily solve the ingredients field. I don't know if my understanding is good

Comment: Odd. Try this: Add a `console.log(id_dish)` inside the `ingredients` resolver. Now run each query (one with `restaurants` as the root and one with `dishes`. I suspect when you run the `restaurants` query, `id_dish` is undefined, null or some other wrong value and that's what's causing your API to return an empty array.

Comment: You might also try logging the entire `parent` object to confirm that the resolver is receiving the same sort of object. It *should* -- since in both cases the parent field is just making a request to `${mainURL}/dishes`. But maybe the `id_restaurant` query parameter in the URL changes the shape of the payload somehow?

Comment: I made a mistake...!! I checked the REST API and this has a specific endpoint for the ingredients of restaurant dishes in wich includes id_restaurant and id_dishes ... something like this ..... https://my_apy_example/ingredients?id_dish={id_dish}&id_restaurant={id_restaurant} ............!! In a api request if I try to get the ingredients of a dish wich belongs to a restaurant, the response is [] ..... That was always the problem...... !! .. I made a basic mistake